# Best practices for a single reusable UIView class to appear over multiple ViewControllers along a specific pathway?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So I have a ViewController which handles a stopwatch type function, but the user is able to browse content related to the task being timed in separate view controllers. When they view this content, I want a minimized version of the stopwatch (no bigger than a typical header) to appear over the task-related content screens.

Currently I've built this in IB and I've duplicated it and its controls across each ViewController, and I update the timer using Notifications.

I'm sure that there is a better way to do this though. I'd like to build a 'UIView countdown header' module, IE code module once and reuse as opposed to duplicate.

So,

1) what is the suggested approach to this?

2) Would it be best practice to code this mini-timer header UIView as a custom class and pass it to each ViewController via segue?

3) Is there a way to achieve this in IB without having to code it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nib and sub class that then load that nib whenever it's needed.